# Drupal: importing thousands of lines from a mysql database. Easy?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need to import a big databases into Drupal CCK nodes.

Let's say I have 1 million of lines to import. Each line is a Drupal node, and each field is a CCK field. (this is the mapping I have in mind).

Is this something risky to do, or do you think I can easily import the data in my new Drupal installation ?

Could you suggest me tools or modules for the import ? (the original database is Mysql.. should I perform some intermediate step such as export the database files to text files.. or.. ? )

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be pretty easy. You should use the [migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate), [migrate extras](http://drupal.org/project/migrate_extras), [table wizard](http://drupal.org/project/tw), [schema](http://drupal.org/project/schema) and [views](http://drupal.org/project/views).
You setup the tables that you need to import in table wizard. In Migrate you create import jobs and map the fields. And then you can run the import job. It is surprisingly easy. The migrate extras enables importing more cck fields like filefields. You can also run the imports from drush so you don't run into the execution time limit.

There is also a great tutorial over at lullabot.
http://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-data-imports-migrate-and-table-wizard